# pH Changes in primary cells

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, ph, electrolysis

> Primary Cells - pH changes during discharge

**`Alkaline Cell:`**

**Manganese Dioxide Zinc Alkaline Cell**

**Anode (-)** 
$\ce {Zn(s) + 2OH^{−}(aq) → ZnO(s) + H2O(l) + 2e^{−}}$

**Cathode (+)**
$\ce {2MnO2(s) + H2O(l) + 2e^{−} → Mn2O3(s) + 2OH^{−}(aq)}$

**Overall**
$\ce {Zn(s) + 2MnO2(s) → ZnO(s) + Mn2O3(s)}$

- $\ce {OH-}$ ions are consumed at the anode
- $\ce {OH-}$ ions are formed at the cathode
- $\ce {same[OH^{−}]}$
- pH - no change

Is this correct? Do pH changes occur during the discharge process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the reaction does not produce hydroxide ions. But the solution is already basic (probably between pH 12 and 14).

Comment: I fixed your edits - because I wrote it wrong at first... or have I corrected it incorrectly? Can you take a look again?

Comment: So was my answer.

Comment: so there is no change - but the solution remains basic?

Comment: Yes, the solution remains basic.